# NoSQL or SQL for a linking graph

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb, nosql

I need to model a database (which might get huge over time) that is basically just a links list. What I mean is: the database will just link entities together in the same way as graph nodes are linked. There would be no additional data aside from the nodes' names but the following queries will need to be fast:

- which nodes are linked to a particular node?
- search all nodes with a particular name (or part of it)

If implemented with a relational database, this will probably have to be modeled with a single table where each row is a connection of one node with another (multiple might exist). I'm not sure if something like MongoDB could be a good choice here.. I don't need horizontal scaling but a relational database with a single table looks stupid.

Any advice?

Comment: A relational database with a single table is fine if you model a single relation. unless you are only interested in edges of your link graph as opposed to paths, I'd recommend to use a graph database (sorry, I have no experience with any particular product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoSql databases are a huge family of databases.

MongoDb is a document database.

Choose a *Graph Database* like *neo4j* that is closer to your needs.